# is this right to use coroutines in a non coroutine context

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, withcontext

Having a `Processor` class,  trying to replace some of the code with coroutines. Since it is in a non coroutines context so `val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + serviceJob)` is added and used for start coroutines.

Added `CoroutineScope`,  and using `serviceScope.launch{}` in the place which was using Thread{}.start().

Inside the function restart(), it replaced the using of `CountDownLatch` with

```
serviceScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    doReset()
                }
            }
```

Question:  this launch/withContext actually does not stop the code execution of the next `if (!conDoProcess)` -- so it fails to do what the `latch` used to do.

what is the right way to stop the code execution until the `doReset()` . is done?

Another question,  when dispose this `Processor` object it calls `serviceScope.cancel()`,

what is the difference if call with `serviceJob.cancel()`?

```
class Processor {

    private val serviceJob = Job()
    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + serviceJob)

            .........

    /* return false if the it does not start the processing */
    fun restart(): Boolean {

        synchronized(_lock) {

            .........

            // 1.old code using latch to wait

            /******************
            val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
            streamThreadPoolExecutor.execute {

                doReset()  //

                latch.countDown()
            }
            latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // wait at most for 3 seconds if no one calls countDown

            *******************/

            // 2. change to using coroutines to suspend

            serviceScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    doReset()
                }
            }

            // wait until reset is done
            if (!conDoProcess) {// the doRest() should update conDoProcess
                return false
            }

            for (i in providers.indices) {
                val pr = provider[i]
                serviceScope.launch {
                    pr.doProcess()
                }
            }

            return true
        }
    }

    fun dispose() {
        synchronized(_lock) {

            .........
            serviceScope.cancel()

            // or should it use
            // serviceJob.cancel()
            //==========>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it used the `serviceScope.launch` wrong, it should include the rest part after the blocking part `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, but inside the `serviceScope.launch`.

```
        // 2. change to using coroutines to suspend

        serviceScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                doReset()
            }

            // wait until reset is done
            if (!conDoProcess) {// the doRest() should update conDoProcess
              return false
            }

            for (i in providers.indices) {
              val pr = provider[i]
              serviceScope.launch {
                  pr.doProcess()
              }
            }   
        }

        return true
```